# $30$ points in a $5\times5$ square

Tags: geometry

If $30$ points are placed inside a $5\times5$ square, what is the largest possible value for the minimum distance among all pairs of points? I have no idea on how to start this question.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof or are you posing this to us?

Comment: A possible and correct answer would be: $10$.

Comment: It's not 10. I already know how to answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Well, you certainly cannot deny that there will always be at least two points which are located not more than 10 units apart from each other.

Comment: Or rather, not 10, but $5\sqrt2$, since that's the diagonal of the square :)

Answer (score 5):

There is an intimate relation between the following two questions:

- The question above: if *N* points are in a unit square, what is the largest possible value for the distance between the closest pair of points?
- [What is the smallest square that will hold *N* unit circles?](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirinsqu/)

The two questions are related as follows: if the shortest distance is $d$ and the smallest square's side length $s$, $s=2+\frac2{d}$. The question above corresponds to the $N=30$ case.

The optimal packing of [30 circles in a square](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq30.html) is known, for which the square side length is $$\frac{126+5\sqrt{10}}{13}$$
and the corresponding shortest distance
$$\frac{20-\sqrt{10}}{75}$$
This last value is for a unit square; for a $5\times5$ square, multiply this by 5 to get the answer to the original question as
$$\frac{20-\sqrt{10}}{15}=1.1225148\dots$$

Comment: Can you explain in simple way. It's difficult to understand.

Comment: Huh? What exactly do you not understand about this answer? I had to edit your question so all of **us** could understand it.

Comment: I have given comment where my answer is 5√2/30. Simple explanation being all points can be maximum placed equidistant in the diagonal of the square.

Comment: I didn't understand from "optimal packing"...

Comment: @Saurab Your placement of points above is far from optimal. Just by placing the points on the vertices of a 5 × 5 grid of squares in the square (there are 36 such vertices) I can get an answer of 1.

Comment: "Optimal packing" means "the placement of shapes (circles here) without overlapping, completely inside another shape (a square here), such that the size of the enclosing shape is the smallest possible". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is $2r$, where $r$ is the solution of $30\pi r^2=5^2+20r+\pi r^2$. (Numerically that makes $2r\approx 1.28995$). The reason is that if all points are at least $2r$ apart, the $30$ disks of radius $r$ around the points are pairwise disjoint and are contained in the shape obtained by widening the square by $r$ in each of the four directions (with rounded corners).

This is still very wasteful.

Comment: Ok you got me.  I espectfully deleted my answer in favor of your superior one and give an upvote.

Comment: If there existed a distribution of points with that $r$, then the $30$ circles would need to be an exact partition of the widened square. Obviously that's not possible. This answer is not wasteful, on the contrary it is an overestimate of $r$.

Comment: @McFry With "wasteful" I wanted to express that the bound is far from sharp. As it turns out, my bound is still closer to the $\sqrt 2$ bound posted (and deleted) by *Oscar Lanzi* than to the definite bound given by *Parcly Taxel*.

Comment: Maybe to clarify, if any third person is placing 30 points in 5*5 unit square, which I can't see, I can challenge him that there will be at least ---------- units distance between two points. I feel it's either 5√2/30 unit distance. But not sure. Also by pigeonhole principle, it comes to √2/2. Help me.